# Connect view with viewmodel to share an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, listbox

I can't show in a ListBox object my ObservableCollection. How could I do it?

Here is my elemental code:

C#

```
    public ObservableCollection<string> Collection { get; set; }
private void Add(Window window)
    {
            Collection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            Collection.Add("First Item");
    }
```

XAML

```
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Collection, Mode=TwoWay}"      HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" />
```

Comment: Not sure what that is, but it isn't mvvm.  It's a mess, yes, but not a mvvm mess.  `private void Add(Window window)` you're just thrashing about at this point.  You should stop and read up on MVVM and how it works in wpf.  Create a couple simple applications (listbox, button, and a view model) and see how things fit together.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your collection in the view model's constructor, or call your `Add()` method from the constructor.

BTW, your `Add()` method doesn't use its parameter.